# TYPO3: dropdown login box (menu)

Tags: typo3, fluid

I would like to create a dropdown login box in the menu. When users hover over "login" in the menu, it shows the login or register form. I found an example here: https://www.planet-sports.com/en/

I am quite new to TYPO3 so I don't know where I should start. Is there a way to do this with Typoscript only or should I modify the navbar with html and javascript? What is the best way to do this ?

EDIT: I am using a custom theme (not done by myself)

The Menu is called in a "header.html" file like this:

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse" role="navigation">
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="menu.navbar" />
    </nav>
```

Typoscript for the navbar:

```
    menu.navbar = HMENU
menu.navbar {
    entryLevel = 0
    excludeUidList = 112

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        stdWrap.dataWrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav colum-{register:count_menuItems}">|</ul>

        NO {
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="first" >|</li> |*| <li id="navbar{field:uid}">|</li> |*| <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="last navbar-right">|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
            ATagTitle.field = description // subtitle
        }

        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="first active">|</li> |*| <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="active">|</li> |*| <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="last active navbar-right">|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
            ATagTitle.field = description // subtitle
        }

        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
            ATagTitle.field = description // subtitle
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="dropdown first">|</li> |*| <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="dropdown">|</li> |*| <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="dropdown last">|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
            linkWrap = |<span class="caret"></span>
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        }

        ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="dropdown first active">|</li> |*| <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="dropdown active">|</li> |*| <li id="navbar{field:uid}" class="dropdown last active">|</li>
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>

        NO.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = |*| <li class="odd">|</li> || <li class="even">|</li> |*|

        ACT = 1
        ACT.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = |*| <li class="odd active">|</li> || <li class="even active">|</li> |*|
    }

    3 = TMENU
    3 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="dropdown-submenu">|</ul>

        NO.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>

        ACT = 1
        ACT.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first active">|</li> |*| <li class="active">|</li> |*| <li class="active last">|</li>
    }

    4 = TMENU
    4 {
        wrap = <ul class="dropdown-submenu-1">|</ul>

        NO.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>

        ACT = 1
        ACT.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first active">|</li> |*| <li class="active">|</li> |*| <li class="active last">|</li>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all: the visibility of a layer can be handled with CSS (even fade in/fade out or explode/implode). just put all content in a div which is included in the trigger div.
How you get your content into this div depends of the kind you build your page. fluid-template, marker-template, pure typoscript.
there are multiple ways to get the login form (and other content) into the div: create it by typoscript, get the content from a fix page, get the content from a special column which is inherited to all subpages (slide).

just be a little be more specific what your current configuration is, what you are familiar with and what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was think about fluid template (after <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="menu.navbar" />). I could use the login form from the extension "fe_users" and the register form from "femanager".

Comment: The menu is something you could provide as variable to the fluid-template. no neccessarity to call it via cObject-VH.  aside of that you have not clearly stated which way you want use for including the login form/plugin. Including plugins via typoscript (either per fluid-variable or cObject-VH) may be complicated as some options are configured easier if you have a normal content element. therefore I recommend an include via special column which gets inherited to all subpages.

Comment: I added more details about my configuration in the OP.  Sorry I don't know what you mean with "special column". I guess I have to add an item to the Menu with Typoscript now ?

Comment: It's not about the menu. it's more about how do you work with fluid and typoscript. what is your current markup (fluid)? what is the markup you want to archieve? the 'special column' could be an additional column in your backend layout which could contain the login plugin CE. (only one CE, which is visible on all pages)